# Python spanish problem codec can't encode character

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, decode

I can't do the typical

```
encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')
```

Because I loose the ñ and the áéíóú characters.

What can I do?

Thank you very much

Comment: What do you want? The whole purpose of  `encode('utf-8').decode('ascii', 'ignore')` is to remove ("ignore") non-ascii characters (such as ñ and accented vowels.) It's use is only typical in cases where that's what's desired. In order to receive good advice, you need to say what exactly you want.

Comment: I have this error trying to write a variable in a file: UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u25c6' in position 197: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I can solve the error doing the code I put but I lose the ñ and accented ones.

Comment: So maybe your initial file is not `utf-8`, and so you should check which it is your encoding, and do to decode correctly, without such very bad tricks. In general never copy lines which you do not fully understand. The `ignore` has security implications. As Unicode recommend: we should not ignore, but ev. substitute with a placeholder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved¡

```
re.sub(r"[^0-9A-Za-zÁ-Úá-ú \t]+", ' ',
```

Thank you